# "hard" supervision in image segmentation with python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

There are several packages and methods for segmentation in Python. However, if I know apriori that certain pixels (and no others) correspond to a particular object, how can I use that to segment other objects?

Which methods implemented in python would lend themselves to this approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at semi-automated image segmentation.  Image segmentation in a semi-automated perspective means that you **know** before hand what class certain pixels belong to - either foreground or background.  Given this *a priori* information, the goal is to minimize an energy function that best segments the rest of the pixels into foreground and background.

The best two methods that I know of are Graph Cuts and Random Walks.  If you want to study the fundamentals of both of them, you should read the canonical papers by Boykov (Graph Cuts) and Grady (Random Walks) respectively:

- Graph Cuts - Boykov: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Papers/ijcv06.pdf
- Random Walks - Grady: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~nray1/CMPUT615/MRF/grady2006random.pdf

For Graph Cuts, OpenCV uses the GrabCut algorithm, which is an extension of the original Graph Cuts algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GrabCut.  Essentially, you surround a box around the object you want segmented, and Gaussian Mixture Models are used to model the foreground and background and the object will be segmented from the background inside this box.   Additionally, you can add foreground and background markers inside the box to further constrain the solution to ensure you get a good result.

Take a look at this official OpenCV tutorial for more details:  http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html

For Random Walks, this is implemented in the [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) library and here's a great tutorial on how to get the segmentation up and running off of their official website: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_random_walker_segmentation.html

---

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks rayryeng, I hadn't thought of it that way

Comment: @user3391229 - No problem at all.  The problem that you are attempting to solve is very well known and those are the best two techniques that I know of that have good results.  Good luck!